# I need to retrieve historical information from the http://service.iris.edu/fdsnws/dataselect/docs/1/builder/ API

Tags: python, api

I need to retrieve historical for the earthquakes in Japan and Chile, and I know this websites has an API. Nevertheless, I cannot seem how to used correctly.

Help will be trully appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL builder that i on the page you posted. Than you make GET request in you python code to the generated url.

This is tutorial how to make GET request in Python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/

Then you will recieve response with desired data.

Comment: The problem with the URL builder is that it retrieves information every thousandths of a second for the time windows that I want. I try adjusting the Minimum Length (seconds) parameter but it does now work and I just need the characteristics of earthquakes through time